# appsettings.json change connection string on runtime

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, database-connection, appsettings

Asume i have 4 servers  with 4 dbs they have all the same catalog.
it is possible to change {serverLocation} on runtime ?

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  
"Euro": "Data Source=campus-db-{serverLocation};Initial Catalog=Shool;Integrated Security=True"}
```

method should look something like that:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStock(int id, string serverLocation)
    {

        var queryStock = _context.TblItem.FindAsync(id);

        return Ok(queryStock);
    }
```

The idea is that i need only 1 DBContext 1 Model because on all 4 servers the catalog are the same and database structure

Comment: Sorry, I have a question here, why you have 4 databases and they have the same catalog?  cluster？

Comment: Hi Tiny,
lets say you have 4 location and more France, GB, Germany, Austria, Poland.
In each location you have an server the structure in each location is the same.
They are not in a cluster.

Best Regards,
Ivica

Comment: global distribution, yeah, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, please check.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => 
    {
         var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        var httpRequest = httpContext.Request;
        // Now you can get access to the http context here, do what ever you want to do here with httpRequest.
        // write conditional statements here like
        if(somecondition-a)
         options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:Connection-A"));
        if(somecondition-b)
         options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:Connection-B"));
    }
}
```

For more infor check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)

If that do not help, try this approach

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options =>
   {
         var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        var httpRequest = httpContext.Request;
        // Now you can get access to the http context here, do what ever you want to do here with httpRequest.
    // write conditional statements here like
    if(somecondition-a)
     options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:Connection-A"));
    if(somecondition-b)
     options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:Connection-B"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mate,

thanks for the answer i am not sure how to handle the if statements over HttpClient ?

best regards

Comment: First tell me how many different connection strings you have? What is your logic to identify a connection string based on user. Then I can help you resolve your issue. I believe named registrations will work for you. But to provide you more info you should provide me info to generalize your use case. @IvicaVasiljevic

Comment: Hi @MaheshBongani,

i have 4 connection strings.

 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetStock(int id, string serverLocation){
  serverLocation = should be  the identify for the connection
}

"ConnectionStrings": {  
"France": "Data Source=campus-db-fr;Initial Catalog=Shool;Integrated Security=True"},
{  
"Germany": "Data Source=campus-db-de;Initial Catalog=Shool;Integrated Security=True"},{  
"England": "Data Source=campus-db-gb;Initial Catalog=Shool;Integrated Security=True"},{  
"Poland": "Data Source=campus-db-pl;Initial Catalog=Shool;Integrated Security=True"}

Comment: Check my update to the answer. Added a way to access HttpContext for getting dynamic Db connection. @IvicaVasiljevic

Comment: I solved it in a different way.
@Mahesh Bongani

Comment: @IvicaVasiljevic If you have figured it, please share the solution. It would help others also.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh  Bongani, i did it but some people recommend deletion without saying anything ^_- can you review my code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this but i am not sure

```cs
IConfiguration _configuration;
public StockManager(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public object FindAsync(int id,serverLocation)
{
    //do stuff
    _configuration.GetConnectionString($"ConnectionStrings:{serverLocation}");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).